# Wrong distance in geonear method with Doctrine MongoDB ODM

Tags: mongodb, symfony, doctrine-odm

I'm using DoctrineMongoDBBundle with Symfony2 and I've a problem with geocoordinates. This works fine but when the longitude is for example like that: 0.635467 the code doesn't work. I have more geocoordinates and only fails when it begins with 0. and the distance field is NULL.

This is my code:

```
$locations = $dm->createQueryBuilder('MyBundle:Location')
                    ->field('id')->in($arrayIds)
                    ->field('geocoordinates')
                    ->geoNear($geocodes['lat'],$geocodes['lon'])
                    ->getQuery()->execute()->toArray();
```

I'm following this link: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/latest/reference/geospatial-queries.html but with the geonear method.

Comment: The geospatial search wants the order of longitude, latitude. Is that how you have your documents stored?

Comment: Yes, the problem is only with latitude/longitude which begin with "0."

Answer (score 2):

The `geoNear()` query builder method is not intended to be used on a field. `near()` is the builder method that would follow a `field()` focus. You can see what both of these builder methods do in [Builder.php](https://github.com/doctrine/mongodb/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/MongoDB/Query/Builder.php) within the doctrine/mongodb project. Note that `geoNear()` changes the query type (similar to what `update()` does). The query type is then checked in [Query.php](https://github.com/doctrine/mongodb/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/MongoDB/Query/Query.php) (follow the switch statement) and determines how we issue the query on the collection. Some are actual query operations, but things like map/reduce and geoNear are commands.

See if the following code works:

```
$dm->createQueryBuilder('MyBundle:Location')
    ->geoNear($geocodes['lat'],$geocodes['lon'])
    ->field('id')->in($arrayIds)
    ->getQuery()->execute()->toArray();
```

If not, please debug the values that Query.php passes to the `Collection::near()` method. Alternatively, you can debug the entire query array generated by the builder by using the `Query::getQuery()` method.