# Doctrine MongoDB geoNear() dinstance set to 0 when adding additional query

Tags: php, mongodb, doctrine-orm, geolocation, doctrine-odm

I'm using a `geoNear()` to calculate distances between objects in my Mongo database.
The query works perfectly, even with addition field filters such as `->field('name')->equals($name)` etc...

This automatically populates a mapped field @ODM\Distance on the object.

```
$this->getQueryBuilder()
->geoNear((float) $query['near_longitude'], (float) $query['near_latitude'])
->spherical(true)
->distanceMultiplier(self::EARTH_RD_KM);
```

If I add an `->field('id')->in($array)` however this distance is suddenly 0.
I'm not really sure where the information is lost.
Is this a limitation on how $in works on MongoDB?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? What's your final query which gives wrong result or correct result? Update your question with these details.

Comment: where are you adding ->field('id')->in($array)?  I'm guessing you are changing the meaning of your query - show the full query with this new part added.

Comment: $this->getQueryBuilder()->field('id')->in($filters['ids_set']);
$filters['ids_set'] is an array of ids and it gives me back the correct subset of results but without distance, which is now zero. If I don't filter with ->in it gives me the distance. @AsyaKamsky

Comment: Anyway, I think you can probably look at answer to this question here which shows an example of correct syntax: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14756264/431012

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use "maxDistance" function

like this;

```
$this->getQueryBuilder()
    ->geoNear((float) $query['near_longitude'], (float)$query['near_latitude'])      

    ->spherical(true) 

    ->maxDistance(self::YOUR_DESIRED_KM_RADIUS / self::EARTH_RD_KM)

    ->distanceMultiplier(self::EARTH_RD_KM);
```

That way it sets a radius for your query.